# How to reflect select result of UISegmentedControl in Firebase'S Database

Tags: swift, database, firebase, uisegmentedcontrol

Hello I'm newbie in programming (Swift/Firebase) and developing  application. Now is trying to make a user profile to be connected to database. I could do it for TextFields data, but cannot do the same with UISegmentedControl for Male/Female switch.

```
@IBAction func saveProfileButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if nameTextField.text! == "" {
            print("enter something")
        } else {
            addUser()
        }
}

@objc func valuChange() {
    switch genderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            let zero = String("Male")
        case 1:
           let one = String("Female")
        default:
            return
    }
}

func addUser() {
    let  genderChanged = genderSegControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.valuChange), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    let userGender = String(describing: genderChanged!)
    let uidUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let user = ["...": ..., "userGender":  userGender as! String] 
    refUsers.child(uidUser!).setValue(user)
}
```

but when I check Firebase's Database nodes it shows `"userGender: Optional(())"` and only. I tried in many different ways but couldn't get it to be shown like `"userGender: Male"` or `"userGender: Female"`.

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create outlet for `UISegementControl` in your `ViewController`, say `genderControl`.
2. In `addUser()` function, use the `selectedIndex` of the `UISegementControl` to determine the value as follows, say `index 0` is for `MALE` & `1` is for `FEMALE` then:

   `let gender = genderControl.selectedIndex == 0 ? "Male" : "Female"`
3. Now set this value `gender` in user dictionary, i.e.

   `let user = ["...": ..., "userGender":  gender]`

Comment: winny thank you! Great! It worked! Very simple and effective!

Comment: Can you upvote the answer if that worked for you! and choose it as the correct answer